# Size of sample with sampleBy in pyspark 2.4.0

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, sample

I have a dataframe `df` in pyspark 2.4.0, and I would like to get a sample of it using `sampleBy`. It contains a column `category`, and I have a dict as such to sample with :

```
dict = {
"cat_A" : 0.1,
"cat_B" : 0.5, 
"cat_C" : 0.4
}
```

I would like my sample to have 5 000 rows and
If I use the function `sampleBy` like this : `df_sampled = df.sampleBy(col = 'category', fractions = fraction, seed = 1)` the resulted dataframe has the right proportion of each category but it doesn't seem the function has a parameter to choose the size of the sample.

Do you know how it could be done ?

I have around 100 000 rows in my initial dataframe, with ~10 other columns so I could switch to Python directly with Pandas or scikit-learn for example, but I don't know either if there is a solution there.

Comment: Can you add bit more of your code that you have so far?

Comment: Good question. I am also stuck here.

Comment: Please check the link for the correct answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608649/pyspark-sample-size-issue-when-using-sampleby-to-perform-stratified-sampling/75612613#75612613

Answer (score 1):

I think you can scale the fractions according to the number of rows you want, and then set the final size of the dataframe using `limit`:

```
fraction = {
"cat_A" : 0.1,
"cat_B" : 0.5,
"cat_C" : 0.4
}

scale = 5000 / df.count() / sum(fraction.values())
fraction = {k, v * scale for (k, v) in fraction.items()}

df_sampled = df.sampleBy(col = 'category', fractions = fraction, seed = 1).limit(5000)
```

Just to make sure you get 5000 rows (and not less), you might use a slightly larger number in the `scale` line, e.g. 5100.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually the fractions I have are lower than 0.1, I gave them as an example for the post. That results in `df.sampleBy(col = 'category', fractions = fraction, seed = 1)` having fewer than 500 rows.

The real values are :  `fraction = {"a_0-2":0.05,
"a_10-19":0.0125,
"a_3-9":0.0375,
"b_0-2":0.125,
"b_10-19":0.03125,
"b_3-9":0.09375,
"c_0-2":0.1,
"c_10-19":0.025,
"c_3-9":0.075,
"d_0-2":0.125,
"d_10-19":0.03125,
"d_3-9":0.09375,
"e_0-2":0.1,
"e_10-19":0.025,
"e_3-9":0.09375}`

Comment: @AntoineFernandes I edited my answer to normalize the sampling fractions. See if that helps?

Comment: I found the solution. It should be as following```fraction.update((k, v * scale) for (k, v) in fraction.items())```

Comment: @mck The ```limit()``` does not work. Since the error message is quite long, and I can not post it there.