# PySpark: sample size issue when using .sampleBy() to perform stratified sampling

Tags: pyspark, sampling

I am using PySpark to implement stratified sampling. The column to be stratified is called `cat`, and it has three levels: `A`, `B`, `C`. In addition, I only want to sample `10%` of the population. In the following code, `fraction` represents the percentage of each category level in the original dataset.

```
fraction = {
     "A": 0.90,
     "B": 0.09,
     "C": 0.01
}
per = 0.1
sample_size = round(df.count() * per, 0)
scale = per/sum(fraction.values())
fraction.update((k, v * scale) for (k, v) in fraction.items())

df_sample = df.sampleBy(col = 'cat', fractions = fraction, seed = 666)
```

The code above is adapted from the following link:

[Size of sample with sampleBy in pyspark 2.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65615934/size-of-sample-with-sampleby-in-pyspark-2-4-0)

However, for the result, I found the fraction is not the same as the original data. Instead, it is quite off. The result is as following:

```
A: 0.989
B: 0.0105
C: 1.393E-4
```

Any clue? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the total number of records of your data?

As you mentioned that the `fraction` represents the percentage of each category level in the original dataset, and you would like to keep the same `fraction` after you do the sampling, you can skip the scale calculation actually:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A', ) for _ in range(900)] + [('B', ) for _ in range(90)] + [('C', ) for _ in range(10)],
    schema=['cat']
)
df.groupBy('cat').count().orderBy('cat').show(100, False)
+---+-----+
|cat|count|
+---+-----+
|A  |900  |
|B  |90   |
|C  |10   |
+---+-----+
```

Just keep all category `0.1` in the `fraction`:

```
df.sampleBy(func.col('cat'), fractions={'A': 0.1, 'B': 0.1, 'C': 0.1}, seed=666)\
    .groupBy('cat').count().orderBy('cat').show(100, False)
+---+-----+
|cat|count|
+---+-----+
|A  |95   |
|B  |12   |
|C  |1    |
+---+-----+
```

Although the ratio is not exactly the same of the original one, it shouldn't have such big difference compared to yours:

```
95 / (95 + 12 + 1), 12 / (95 + 12 + 1), 1 / (95 + 12 + 1)
>>> (0.8796296296296297, 0.1111111111111111, 0.009259259259259259)
```